# print element from list json

Tags: python, json, list, printing

I have a list a load from a txt file which is formatted with JSON, the program prints out the element i want (by index, requested from user) although it prints the list in an unwanted format

```
elif choice == 'v':
    # View a joke.
    # See Point 6 of the "Requirements of admin.py" section of the assignment brief.
    jokeIndex = input('Joke number to view: ')
    index = int(jokeIndex)
    file = open('data.txt', 'r')
    data = json.load(file)
    print(data[index])

    file.close();
    pass
```

it prints it literally how it is written in the txt file, not just the actually elements

```
Choose [a]dd, [l]ist, [s]earch, [v]iew, [d]elete or [q]uit.  
v
Joke number to view: 1   
{'setup': 'whats brown and sticky', 'punchline': 'a stick'}
```

although i would like it to output something like this

```
Q:whats brown and sticky?  A: a stick
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format the output more

```
elif choice == 'v':

jokeIndex = input('Joke number to view: ')
index = int(jokeIndex)
file = open('data.txt', 'r')
data = json.load(file)
print('Q: ' + data[index]['setup'])
print('A: ' + data[index]['punchline'])

file.close();
pass
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than

```
print(data[index])
```

You should put something like this:

```
print('Q: {setup}? A: {punchline}'.format(**data[index])
```

The reason is because it is a dictionary, which you can access by keys.
The way I put `**data[index]` is called dictionary expansion.
It automatically formats the string based on the keys available.

You can see the keys and values in the dictionary using the following example code:

```
print(data[index].keys())
print(data[index].values())
```

You can also return key:value pairs with the following:

```
for key, value in data[index].items():
    print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = "Q:{}? A: {}"
row = data[index]
f1 = f.format(row.get('setup'), row['punchline'])
print f1
```